# Typescript download PDF file have empty contant

Tags: javascript, java, file, pdf, download

I have a script to download different type files from server side. The code works for text/xml but when the downloaded pdf file is empty.

```js
let response = this.http.get(this.Url , new Headers({responseType: 'blob'}))
      .subscribe(doc => {
        if (doc) {
          let contentType = doc.headers.get("Content-Type");
          let name = doc.headers.get("Content-Disposition").split("=")[1];
          let blob = new Blob([doc.text()], {type: contentType});
          let a = window.document.createElement("a");
          a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          a.download = name;
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
      },
        error => this.msgService.showError(this.msgs, error));
```

**My server**
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("-----")
    public Response getDocument(@PathParam("documentId") Long documentId) throws Exception {

```
    Document document = ---------------;

    return ResponseHelper.createOkResponse(
            output -> IOUtils.write(document.documentContent(), output),
            document.documentName(),
            document.documentType()
    );
}
```

I can see the doc.text() is returning some byte[]. Also tried {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}.  can anyone advise how can i display for pdf ? 
Thanks